# ASP.NET - owin static WebMethod - cookie not validated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, owin

My owin is setup to use cookie based authentication with OpenIdConnect like this:

```
        var options = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
               OnValidateIdentity = cookieValidateIdentityContext =>
               {
                cookieValidateIdentityContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1);
                return Task.FromResult(30);
               }
            }
        }
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options);
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() {.....})
```

I have a static WebMethod like this

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static String GetJsonData(string query)
    {
        var user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        .....
    }
```

This works fine but if the user leaves the browser for more than 20 mins, auth fails. HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.

This happens even though my cookie is set to expire after 30 days. Is there any way to forcefully validate cookie and autenticate? I am not using forms based auth.

Also, once the 20+ mins pass, the `cookieValidateIdentityContext` func is not called. If I set breakpoint in cookieValidateIdentityContext, before 20 mins, the breakpoint is hit but not after.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article [Cookie Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) `SlidingExpiration` is causing issue try to set it in web.config.

SlidingExpiration - a flag indicating if the cookie expiration date will be reset when the more than half of the ExpireTimeSpan interval has passed. The new expiry date will be moved forward to be the current date plus the ExpireTimespan. An absolute expiry time can be set by using the AuthenticationProperties class when calling SignInAsync. An absolute expiry can improve the security of your application by limiting the amount of time for which the authentication cookie is valid.

Comment: It seems SlidingExpiration can be only for Form based authentication. I am using owin here

Comment: the link i have provided is for OWIN